# Template matching - how to ignore pixels

Tags: c#, image-processing, template-matching

I'm trying to find a digit within an image. To test my code I took an image of the digit and then used AForge's [Exhaustive Template Matching](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/17494328-ef0c-dc83-1bc3-907b7b75039f.htm) algorithm to search for it in another image. But I think there is a problem in that the digit is obviously not rectangular whereas the image that contains it is. That means that there are a lot of pixels participating in the comparison which shouldn't be. Is there any way to make this comparison while ignoring those pixels? If not in AForge then maybe EMGU/OpenCV or Octave?

Here's my code:

```
Grayscale gray = new GrayscaleRMY();
Bitmap template = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"5template.png");
template = gray.Apply(template);
Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(filePath);
Bitmap sourceImage = gray.Apply(image);
ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.7f);
TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(sourceImage, template);
```

[image: Here's an example image.]

Comment: If the background is affecting the matching, the first step might be to pre-process both images to remove the background.

Comment: How would I do that? A Bitmap object is always rectangular and pixels cannot be set to null AFAIK.

Comment: I mean if you can decide if a pixel is foreground or background, set all background pixels in both images to the same colour (e.g. white or black).

Comment: Ah, OK. That'll be difficult. I was wondering if there was a way to disregard the superfluous pixels.

Comment: Do you have example images we can look at?

Comment: @Johnny: it will be difficult!  This is a difficult problem.

Comment: Forgot to update: I added an example image.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above in the comment, you should preprocess your data to improve matching.

The first thing that comes to mind is [morphological opening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_(morphology)) (erode then dilate) to reduce the background noise

Read in your image and invert it so that your character vectors are white:

[image]

Apply opening with smallest possible structuring element/window (3x3):

[image]

You could try slightly larger structuring elements (5x5):

[image]

Invert it back to the original:

[image]

See if that helps!